# How could I read a JSF session bean from a filter?

Tags: security, jsf, resources, servlet-filters, cdi

I'm searching but I can't find the answer, I need secure resources based on permissions, I can't use a filter because FacesContext is not initialized before and I need load the permissions in my session bean. Some solution avoiding use a filter? PhaseListener, ViewHandler and ResourceHandler can't capture an URL resource request, for example I need denied this direct access: `http://127.0.0.1:8080/test/resources/images/image.jpg`

Thx in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSF stores session scoped managed beans as an attribute of the `HttpSession`, which in turn is just available in a `Filter` by `HttpServletRequest#getSession()`.

```
HttpSession session = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getSession();
SessionBean sessionBean = session.getAttribute("sessionBean");
// ...
```

---

**Update**: as per the comment you seem to be actually using CDI:

> *my filter is triggered before than JSF, I always get a null value when I use getAttribute. I'm using CDI with 'Named' and 'SessionScoped' annotations on my Bean because I need use a interceptor to implement security*

I understood that you were using JSF's own `@ManagedBean` and the initial answer only applies to that. If your bean is already managed by CDI's `@Named`, then just use CDI's own `@Inject` the usual way in the `Filter`.

```
@Inject
private SessionBean sessionBean;
```

In case of JSF `@ManagedBean` you should just add a `if (sessionBean != null)` check. It's irrelevant whether the filter is invoked before JSF servlet or not. Once the session bean has been created by JSF, it won't be `null` in the filter.

Comment: my filter is triggered before than JSF, I always get a null value when I use getAttribute. I'm using CDI with 'Named' and 'SessionScoped' annotations on my Bean because I need use a interceptor to implement security.

Comment: I updated the answer. I didn't expect that you were using CDI because it's pretty straightforward in CDI.

Comment: Ok, I deleted my comment... CDI worked with the abstract class... you are the best... thank you... =)

Comment: sorry for my ignorance, but how exactly Kab is intercepting http://localhost:8080/test/resources/images/image.jpg here? :-(

Comment: @Leo: using a `Filter`.

Comment: isn't the question "How I can intercept an URL resource request in JSF without use a Filter?" :-)

Comment: @Leo: did you read the question? OP considered filter, but dropped the idea because he incorrectly thought he couldn't obtain session scoped JSF managed beans in there. The answer shows how to do that anyway. You can of course also use a phase listener or so, but that's only clumsy among others because  you can't easily map it on specific URL patterns as you apparently faced.

Comment: Got it and I agree with you that your answer is the best one. Although, maybe Kab should re-state the question in the caption IMO