# JSF - Primefaces - how to intercept p:menuitem outcome

Tags: jsf, primefaces, actionlistener, menuitem

I am trying to intercept p:menuitem outcome using a custom ActionListener, but I can't. It seems that if I change outcome to action, it works (of course) but then I can't make f:param inside these links to work.

What's the correct way to intercept p:menuitem outcome?

UPDATE: here's my current approach/idea. Sounds cumbersome to me, but may work. Although, better ways to implement this are welcome -

I am considering using a filter, just like BalusC describes here

[How could I read a JSF session bean from a filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10985528/how-i-can-intercept-an-url-resource-request-in-jsf-without-use-a-filter/10985846)

My initial idea was to intercept any request (not only action ones) and apply some security rules over it.

I did some research and it seems there are many security models for JSF apps, some will restrict by bean methods, some by URL, but in my case, I'd like something that I could control by xhtml.

So I'm going towards something like this - http://www.kianworknotes.com/2013/06/authorization-in-jsf-with-facelets-view.html

I'd like my app to let the user apply permission rules for each xhtml, so I am considering this idea

I can list all xhtml like this

```
ExternalContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
List<String> pages = getResources("/private", ".xhtml");
for (String page : pages) {
    try {
        System.out.println(page);
        System.out.println(getMetaData(context.getResourceAsStream(page)));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
return pages;
```

where

```
private List<String> getResources(String path, String suffix) {
    ExternalContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    Set<String> resources = context.getResourcePaths(path);
    List<String> filteredResources = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String resource : resources) {
        if (resource.endsWith(suffix)) {
            filteredResources.add(resource);
        } else if (resource.endsWith("/")) {
            filteredResources.addAll(getResources(resource, suffix));
        }
    }
    return filteredResources;
}
```

(code above borrowed from here - https://community.jboss.org/thread/189427)

Each xhtml will have its own meta tag like [meta name="module" content="Security"] inside a [h:head]

I can parse each xhtml to extract this information with a SAX parser like

```
private class MyDefaultHandler extends DefaultHandler{
    private String titleName = null;
    private boolean skip = false;

    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        if (!skip && qName.equalsIgnoreCase("meta")) {
            boolean isThis = false;

            for (int i = 0; i < attributes.getLength(); i++) {

                String attributeName = attributes.getLocalName(i);
                String attributeValue = attributes.getValue(i);
                System.out.println("found attribute with localname=" + attributeName + " and value=" + attributeValue);

                if (attributeName.equals("name") && attributeValue.equals("module")){
                    titleName = attributes.getValue(i);
                    isThis = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (isThis){
                for (int i = 0; i < attributes.getLength(); i++) {
                    String attributeName = attributes.getLocalName(i);
                    String attributeValue = attributes.getValue(i);

                    if (attributeName.equals("content")){
                        titleName = attributeValue;
                        skip = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public String getTitleName(){
        return titleName;
    }
}

public String parseTitle(InputStream inputStream) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {

    XMLReader reader = SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser().getXMLReader();

    //if you comment the line below, your parser will take 1 minute EACH XML
    reader.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd", false);

    MyDefaultHandler handler = new MyDefaultHandler();
    reader.setContentHandler(handler);
    InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(new BufferedInputStream(inputStream));
    reader.parse(inputSource);

    return handler.getTitleName();
}
```

finally, I can get some sessionScoped managed bean from inside a filter just as suggested by BallusC

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest arg0, ServletResponse arg1,
        FilterChain arg2) throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) arg0;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) arg1;
    HttpSession session = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getSession();
    Enumeration<String> names = session.getAttributeNames();
    while(names.hasMoreElements()){
        System.out.println(names.nextElement());
    }
    AuthorizationManagerMB authorizationManagerMB = (AuthorizationManagerMB)session.getAttribute("authorizationManagerMB");
    if (authorizationManagerMB == null){
        System.out.println("Filter = not logged");
    }else{
        System.out.println("Filtering = "+request.getRequestURI());
        authorizationManagerMB.doSomething();
    }
```

it's cumbersome :-) I know

but I can manage the access by xhtml even if the user provides a direct URL in the browser, no matter it's using ajax or not

if anyone knows a less cumbersome and more elegant way to do this, allowing the user to configure roles in the fly, it will be welcome :-)

ps. it's interesting how JSF has so little ways to work with xhtml. You can't list, you can't add metadata, you can't retrieve metadata. It's quite bean-centered :-)

Comment: For security issues, using filters is the way to go, as it's the beginning of the http request lifecycle. I also add specific restrictions for GET requests using the `preRenderView` event. Apart from that, controlling if a user has the rights to perform an action is a matter of control layer. You should implement some security stuff there to provide secure access from different points (web-http, web services, rmi..)

Answer (score 1):

An `outcome` generates a simple GET request, which can be used with parameters and doesn't need to be surrounded by a form. In order to execute some logic at server side, you need a POST first.

For your specific case the best choice is to use an **action** method, which let's you perform your operations before navigating to the new view. Just do what you want and return the navigation result matching your destination view:

```xml
<p:menuitem action="#{bean.changePage(param)}" />
```

```java
public String changePage(String param){
    //Do some stuff
    return "page2?faces-redirect=true&includeViewParams=true&p1="+param;
}
```

Additionally you have to catch that parameter in your destination view and set into your bean:

```xml
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="p1" value="#{destinationBean.param}" />
</f:metadata>
```

Comment: thanks. anyway, I was looking for something quite like this approach - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10985528/how-i-can-intercept-an-url-resource-request-in-jsf-without-use-a-filter/10985846 - notice that despite the question says "without filter", it seems I can't avoid using it to intercept the requests

Comment: Other choice would be to perform what you want in your `destinationBean` directly. As your question is too broad I can't predict what you're specifically looking for.